# In Django : How to serialize dict object to json?

Tags: python, django, json, serialization

I have this very basic problem,

```
>>> from django.core import serializers
>>> serializers.serialize("json", {'a':1})
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<console>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.6/django/core/serializers/__init__.py", line 87, in serialize
    s.serialize(queryset, **options)
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.6/django/core/serializers/base.py", line 40, in serialize
    for field in obj._meta.local_fields:
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute '_meta'
>>>
```

How can this be done?

Comment: have a look on my answer please.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Also, since you seem to be using Python 2.6, you could just use the `json` module directly:

```
import json
data = json.dumps({'a': 1})
```

Comment: The Django serializers are for Django model objects and QuerySets. That's why it's looking for a _meta field.

Comment: And the native serializer doesn't do the job: TypeError: <Account: 9de5-2653-000d-81a3 => foo@bar.net> is not JSON serializable

Answer (score 6):

```
from django.utils import simplejson
data = simplejson.dumps({'a': 1})
```

Comment: That works great with python objects, but not so well with Django query sets.

Comment: @Ted: Of course not. To serialize query sets, do what the question shows.

Comment: Looks like the Django guys decided to stick with the built-in json module. As of the end of 2013, simplejson is deprecated and should be replaced with json. https://github.com/pythonforfacebook/facebook-sdk/issues/106

Answer (score 0):

Libraries like `json` or `simplejson` are not really cool for the purpose of serializing django objects, when you can use the serializer from `django.core` in your views:

```
from django.core import serializers


def json_for_model_instance(request, pk):       
    instance = YourModel.objects.get(pk=pk)
    serialized_instance = serializers.serialize('json', [instance, ])

    return HttpResponse(serialized_instance, content_type="application/json")
```